# Solve equation to translate mixed lognormal

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have a mixed lognormal distribution with a mean of 1.0. I need to translate it by a scaler to have a new certain mean.

Mean for Mixed Lognormal distribution:

$.7e^{-0.2+\frac{0.9^2}{2}}+.3e^{-2.5+\frac{1.9^2}{2}}=1$

I need to translate the distribution to get a new mean. For example, to achieve a mean of 100, I need to solve the following for $x$:

$.7e^{-0.2x+\frac{0.9^2}{2}}+.3e^{-2.5x+\frac{1.9^2}{2}}=100$

Is there an algebraic solution for this or do I need numerical analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that, for a new mean $m$, you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=0.7\,e^{-0.2x+\frac{0.9^2}{2}}+0.3\,e^{-2.5x+\frac{1.9^2}{2}}-m$$ which can write
$$f(x)=0.7\,e^{\frac{0.9^2}{2}}\,e^{-0.2x}+0.3\,e^{\frac{1.9^2}{2}}\,e^{-2.5x}-m$$ This can be transformed as a polynomial equation in $t=e^{-0.1x}$ which would be
$$f(t)=0.7\,e^{\frac{0.9^2}{2}}\,t^2+0.3\,e^{\frac{1.9^2}{2}}\,t^{25}-m$$ which cannot be solved analytically.

So, only numerical methods can do the job. Newton method is probably the simplest.

From a practical point of view, since exponential functions vary very fast, it could be a good idea to search for the zero of 
$$g(x)=\log\left(0.7\,e^{-0.2x+\frac{0.9^2}{2}}+0.3\,e^{-2.5x+\frac{1.9^2}{2}} \right)-\log(m)$$ For example, for $m=2$, starting using $x_0=1$ (which is more or less the solution you obtained for $m=1$) the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.0000000 \\
 1 & -0.26400533 \\
 2 & 0.16684341 \\
 3 & 0.23803022 \\
 4 & 0.24049787 \\
 5 & 0.24050085
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is exactly what I needed!